Optimize Persistence Analysis with Rolling Windows in Pandas, Handling Overlaps Between Months
I’m relatively new to Python and coding in general. I’m working on a project to perform persistence analysis in a large dataset and am trying to avoid using for loops for efficiency. I’d appreciate some guidance!
Problem:
I have a DataFrame with an hourly timestamp index and a boolean column (Mask) containing TRUE or FALSE values. I want to identify “persistence windows” where there are X consecutive TRUE values (X being a specified window length). After identifying these windows, I want to group the counts by month to get monthly statistics. But I encounter issues due to overlaps across months.
My Approach:
I’ve used pandas.rolling() to count rolling windows, and I then filter using rolling_result == window_length, which correctly identifies the persistence windows. However, I encounter issues when grouping by month due to overlaps across months.
Here’s an example of my data with a window length of 3h:
data example
When I group the counts of windows by month, I currently get 4 windows for April and 2 windows for May. However, two windows in May result from the overlap with April. Ideally, I’d like the count to be 3 windows for April and 3 for May, by proportionally dividing the overlapping windows:

For April: 2 (full windows) + 0.66 (partial window) + 0.33 (partial
window) = 3
For May: 1 (full window) + 1 (full window) + 0.66
(partial window) + 0.33 (partial window) = 3

Question:
Is there a way to handle these overlaps and attribute partial counts proportionally to each month without using for loops? Is there a vectorized solution in Pandas or another approach that could achieve this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Hope this fulfill your requirement:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    'Date': pd.date_range("1994-04-30 20:00", periods=8, freq="h"),
    'Mask': [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Parameters
window_length = 3  
df['RollingCount'] = df['Mask'].rolling(window=window_length).sum()
df['IsPersistenceWindow'] = df['RollingCount'] == window_length
df['WindowID'] = (df['IsPersistenceWindow'] & ~df['IsPersistenceWindow'].shift(1, fill_value=False)).cumsum()
df['WindowID'] = df['WindowID'].where(df['IsPersistenceWindow'], np.nan)
df['Month'] = df.index.to_period("M")

df_persistence = df.dropna(subset=['WindowID'])
def count_full_contribution(group):
    months = group.index.to_period('M').unique()
    return pd.Series(1, index=months)

window_counts = df_persistence.groupby('WindowID').apply(count_full_contribution).reset_index()

print("Window Counts DataFrame:")
print(window_counts)

window_counts.columns = ['WindowID', 'Month', 'Count']
monthly_counts = window_counts.groupby('Month')['Count'].sum()

print("Monthly Persistence Counts (counting full contributions):")
print(monthly_counts)


